# How to save edited content in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-texteditor

My goal is to save the contents only if the user taps "Save", but to discard the edits when they click "Cancel".
That's why I created two variables that receive the initial values of `note.content` and `note.title`.
Those are the ones that users will actually edit. My aim is to take the edited values and assign them to the note instance, which is what I want to edit, only when the user taps "Save".
However, this is not happening because when I tap "Save", `note.content` and `note.title` remain the same value as before and don't reflect the changes.
I don't know what else to do; if someone could help me with this, I would appreciate it.

```
struct EditNoteView: View {
    @State var note: Note
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @State var editedTitle: String
    @State var editedContent: String
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                TextEditor(text: $editedTitle)
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 50, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                Divider()
                
                TextEditor(text: $editedContent)
                    .font(.body)
                    .frame(maxHeight:.infinity)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                Button("Cancel") {
                    dismiss()
                }
            }
            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                Button("Save") {
                    note.title = editedTitle
                    note.content = editedContent
                    dismiss()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you could try using `@Binding var note: Note` and call `EditNoteView(note: $note, ...)`. You should study the crucial concepts of `State` and `Binding` in SwiftUI.

Answer (score 1):

I would think you want to supply your editor with a `Note` to be edited, then the supplied note is either updated or left unchanged when the view is dismissed, depending on which button was pressed. So the following changes are needed:

- Your editor view also contains a `NavigationStack`. The navigation probably needs to be done outside of the editor, in other words, by a parent view.
- The note with the initial content needs to be supplied by the parent view to the editor as a `Binding`.
- To launch the editor, you probably want an edit button in the parent view.
- Inside the editor, you don't need a separate `State` variable for every property of a `Note`. You just need a temporary copy of the whole `Note`.
- The toolbar needs to be attached to the `VStack` of the editor, not to the `NavigationStack`.
- When it comes to layout, start by letting the views find their natural sizes, then add width and height constraints and padding where needed. A `TextEditor` is greedy and uses all the space available, so you don't need to give it maximum width or maximum height.

Here is a revised version of your example with the changes applied:

```swift
struct Note {
    var title: String
    var content: String
}

struct EditNoteView: View {
    @Binding private var note: Note
    @State private var editedNote: Note
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss

    init(note: Binding<Note>) {
        self._note = note
        self._editedNote = .init(initialValue: note.wrappedValue)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            TextEditor(text: $editedNote.title)
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .frame(height: 50)
            Divider()
            TextEditor(text: $editedNote.content)
                .font(.body)
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 12)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                Button("Cancel") {
                    dismiss()
                }
            }
            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                Button("Save") {
                    note = editedNote
                    dismiss()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var note = Note(title: "Initial title", content: "Initial content")
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(note.title)
                        .font(.title.bold())
                        .padding(.bottom)
                    Text(note.content)
                }
                .padding()
                .border(.gray, width: 2)
                .padding()

                NavigationLink {
                    EditNoteView(note: $note)
                        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                } label: {
                    Label("Edit", systemImage: "pencil")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.